# How to fix was not declared in scope

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I was coding for my assignment that reads a file an sorts them into a domestic or international students and displays there names, scores, and id. 
But I keep getting linker errors and I don't know where my problem is.
(I'm sorry I don't know how to put syntax highlighting in here, but I'm desperate to finish)

**File `student.hpp`**:

```
//header file student.hpp to declare your classes
//use namespace std

#include <string> //you will have to use string in C++
#include <iostream>
#pragma once
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#ifndef DOMESTICSTUDENT_H
#ifndef INTERNATIONALSTUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#define DOMESTICSTUDENT_H
#define INTERNATIONALSTUDENT_H

using namespace std;
class Student
{
public:
  Student(string firstName, string lastName, float cgpa, int researchScore, int id);
  Student();
private:
  void check_id();
};    

class DomesticStudent
{
public:
  DomesticStudent(string province);
  DomesticStudent();
};

class InternationalStudent
{
public:
  InternationalStudent();
  string country;
  int totalScore;
  int TotalScore(int reading, int listening, int writing, int speaking);
};


#endif //ends #ifndef
#endif 
#endif
```

**File `student.cpp`**:

```
//student.cpp to implement your classes
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //file processing
#include <sstream> //formatted string processing
#include <cstdlib> //atof and ato
#include <string>
#include "student.hpp"

using namespace std;

void Student::check_id()
{
  int id= 2021500;
  if (id < 20200000 || id>20210000)
    {
        cout << "Invalid ID. Restart the program";
        return;
    }
}

int InternationalStudent::TotalScore(int reading, int listening, int speaking, int writing)
{
totalScore= reading + listening + speaking + writing;
    return totalScore;
}
class ToeflScore: public InternationalStudent
{
public:
  ToeflScore(int reading, int listening, int writing, int speaking);
  ToeflScore();
  int get_reading(int reading);
  int get_listening(int listening);
  int get_speaking(int speaking);
  int get_writing(int writing);
  void check_score(int reading, int listening, int speaking, int writing);
};    

int ToeflScore::get_reading(int reading)
{
    return reading;
}

int ToeflScore::get_listening(int listening)
{
    return listening;
}

int ToeflScore::get_speaking(int speaking)
{
    return speaking;
}

int ToeflScore::get_writing(int writing)
{
    return writing;
}

void ToeflScore::check_score(int reading, int listening, int speaking, int writing)
{
  if (reading < 0 || reading>30)
    {
        cout << "Invalid reading score. Re-enter.";
        return;
    }
  if (listening < 0 || listening>30)
    {
        cout << "Invalid listening score. Re-enter.";
        return;
    }
  if (speaking < 0 || speaking>30)
    {
        cout << "Invalid speaking score. Re-enter.";
        return;
    }
  if (writing < 0 || writing>30)
    {
        cout << "Invalid reading score. Re-enter.";
        return;
    }
}
```

**File `main.cpp`**:

```
//main.cpp, put your driver code here, 
//you can manipulate your class objects here
#include <iostream> //cin and cout
#include <fstream> //file processing
#include <sstream> //formatted string processing
#include <cstdlib> //atof and ato
#include <string>
#include "student.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ToeflScore score;
    InternationalStudent IS;

    string line;
    ifstream domesticFile("domestic-stu.txt");
    if (!domesticFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file domestic-stu.txt" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    getline(domesticFile, line);
    cout << "File format: " << line << endl;    

    int stu_count = 1;
    while (getline(domesticFile, line)) {

        istringstream ss(line);

        string firstName, lastName, province, s_cgpa, s_researchScore;
        float cgpa;
        int researchScore;

        getline(ss, firstName, ',');    
        getline(ss, lastName, ',');
        getline(ss, province, ',');
        getline(ss, s_cgpa, ',');
        cgpa = atof(s_cgpa.c_str());
        getline(ss, s_researchScore, ',');
        researchScore = atoi(s_researchScore.c_str());

        cout << "Domestic student " << stu_count << " " << firstName << " "
            << lastName << " from " << province << " province has cgpa of "
            << cgpa << ", and research score of " << researchScore << endl;

        stu_count++;
    }

    ifstream internationalFile("international-stu.txt");
    if (!internationalFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file international-stu.txt" << endl;
        return -2;
    }

    string line2;
    getline(internationalFile, line2);
    cout << "File format: " << line2 << endl;

    int int_count = 1;
    while (getline(internationalFile, line2)) {

        istringstream ss(line2);

        string firstName, lastName, country, s_cgpa, s_researchScore;
        float cgpa;
        int researchScore;    

        getline(ss, firstName, ',');
        getline(ss, lastName, ',');
        getline(ss, country, ',');
        getline(ss, s_cgpa, ',');
        cgpa = atof(s_cgpa.c_str());

        getline(ss, s_researchScore, ',');
        researchScore = atoi(s_researchScore.c_str());

        int reading;
        int listening;
        int speaking;
        int writing;

        reading = score.get_reading( reading);
        listening = score.get_listening(listening);
        speaking = score.get_speaking(speaking);
        writing = score.get_writing(writing);

        score.check_score(reading,listening,speaking, writing);
        IS.TotalScore(reading, listening, speaking, writing);

        cout << "International student " << stu_count << " " << firstName << " "
            << lastName << " from " << country << " province has cgpa of "
             << cgpa << ", and research score of " << researchScore << "and a ToeflScore of"<< IS.totalScore<< endl;

        int_count++;
    }

    //close your file
    domesticFile.close();
    internationalFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here the **errors** that I get:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:2: error: ‘ToeflScore’ was not declared in this scope
  ToeflScore score;
  ^
main.cpp:23:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘score’
  ToeflScore score;
             ^
main.cpp:114:13: error: ‘score’ was not declared in this scope
   reading = score.get_reading( reading);
             ^
```

Comment: There is way too much code here. If you spent some time removing unnecessary stuff to create a [mcve], you'd likely realise the issue yourself. It's very likely you could reproduce your issue with about 6 lines of code in a working program, but even say 20 would be suffice, but there are over 200 lines of code here.

Comment: Please edit your post with 1: Build commands; 2) The linker error messages, **verbatim**; 3) Any compilation errors, **verbatim**.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the verbatim messages were at the end of the coding block.  Now it should be clearer.

Comment: Were there also link errors OP or are you mixing up compile and link errors?

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

In `main.cpp` you include standard library files and `students.hpp`.

In this included header, you only define the classes `Student`, `InternationalStuden`, and `DomesticStudent`.  There's no trace of `ToeflScore` in it.  So when you use that (undefined) class, the compiler (not the linker) complains.

#### The solution

You have defined the class `ToeflScore` in `students.cpp`.  Move that class definition to `students.hpp`.  It should then work  (the remaining errors seem to be only solely related to the first one).

Comment: I think this is correct for the compile errors the OP showed. They mentioned link errors but so far the question doesn't show what those are or what build steps were used.

Comment: @paisanco thank you for your confirmation.  Indeed, there is no linker error.  I suppose OP simply misinterpreted the origin of the error message.